# Understanding ado.net connection pools, not closing connections

Tags: c#, ado.net, connection-pooling

What are the ramifications of not closing your connections in a web application?

From what I understand, say if you have 100 connections in your pool, if you don't close your connection, and the timeout on the connection is fairly high, this is what happends under the covers:

1. opening a connection takes a connection from the pool
2. if you don't close it, it will remain open until the timeout expires, and then some background thread will loop through the pool and explicitly close/return the connection back to the pool.

Even though c# is managed, it doesn't mean it will close things for you after the page request ends correct?  That is what the timeout settings are for right?  **Or is the .net runtime smart enough to know that since the page request ended, the connection can be closed?**

Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

Connection pooling means when you close (or dispose your connection) it doesn't actually get closed, it simply gets returned to the pool. This allows the connection to be re-used again.

Any managed object that implements `IDisposable` should be used inside a using statement (well most do, WCF been an obvious exception). With `SqlConnection` this results in close being called, and allows the connection to be re-used.

The garbage collector will pickup un-disposed connection at some point and dispose it, but you will never know when as it's none deterministic.

Sql Connections are a limited resource, and you should close them as soon as possible to ensure you don't run out of connections in the pool

Answer (score 0):

It's always recommended that you explicitly close all connections to release them to the connection pool for use by another process.

If you have a SqlConnection object, it should be released after the page request. This is because both System.Web.UI.Page and SqlConnection objects implement IDisposable. When a request to a Page is done, the Page object is Disposed. When a SqlConnection object is disposed of, the connection is closed. This is why you see most uses of a SqlConnection object implmented inside a using statement:

```
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
  "Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Northwind"))
    {
        connection.Open();      
        // Pool A is created.
    }
```

It's always recommended to close it explicitly or use a using statement.

See this article for more details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx